# Nesting promises with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have a promise that I am using to do database manipulation with mongoose. Using the mpromise library, I am taking `teamMatch` and using it to update the `Team` document. However, the program does not do anything past the line where I update the `Team` (start with var getTeamPromise).

How do I change this code so that I can more easily do what I described above?

```
saveTeamMatch.then(

    function saveTeamMatchToTeam(teamMatch) {

        console.log('TEAM_MATCH in SAVE to TEAM', teamMatch); //works

        // when a team is gotten and a teamMatch is made and saved
        // save the teamMatch to the team
        var getTeamPromise = Team.findOneAndUpdate( { id:1540 }, { $push:{ matches:teamMatch } } ).exec()

        .then(

            function successfullySaveTeamMatchToTeam(team) {
                console.log('TEAM in SUCCESSFUL SAVE', team);
                getTeamPromise.resolve();
            },

            function failToUpdateTeam(err) {
                console.error( err );
                getTeamPromise.resolve();
            }

        )

        .resolve(
            function endFindMatchPromise() {
                saveTeamMatch.end();
            }
        );
    },

    function failToSaveTeamMatch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        saveTeamMatch.end();
    }

);
```

Comment: What is `.resolve()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have misunderstood some things about Promises:

Given `getTeamPromise.then(onResolve, onReject)`:

- In onResolve and onReject the promise is already resolved/rejected, as such you can not alter its state by calling resolve on the same promise
- Your resolve(function()) should be the processed result from the result of the first then
- Normally you should not manipulate the state of promises, and lots of the methods you call are internal methods for creating and fullfilling promises.
- Returning a promise from a onResolve handler will pipe that promise or value into the next `then`

Let me write this out in a — probably — working way:

```
saveTeamMatch.then(function saveTeamMatchToTeam(teamMatch) {
    console.log('TEAM_MATCH in SAVE to TEAM', teamMatch); //works
    // when a team is gotten and a teamMatch is made and saved
    // save the teamMatch to the team
    return Team
        .findOneAndUpdate({id:1540}, {$push:{matches:teamMatch}}).exec()
        .then(function successfullySaveTeamMatchToTeam(team) {
            console.log('TEAM in SUCCESSFUL SAVE', team);
            return team;
        }, function failToUpdateTeam(err) {
            console.error('failedToUpdateTeam', err);
        });
},function failToSaveTeamMatch(err) {
    console.error('saveTeamMatch failed', err);
})
.end();
```